# tornado + momoko doesn't handle connection

Tags: python, postgresql, tornado, psycopg2, momoko

I use tornado (4.2.1) + momoko (2.2.0) + psycopg2 (2.6.1) for small web application and it works ok until PostgreSQL server close connection. Then after every db.execute() command I receive an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.2.1-py2.7-win32.egg\tornado\web.py", line 1415, in _execute
        result = yield result
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.2.1-py2.7-win32.egg\tornado\gen.py", line 870, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.2.1-py2.7-win32.egg\tornado\concurrent.py", line 215, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.2.1-py2.7-win32.egg\tornado\gen.py", line 876, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
      File "server.py", line 63, in get
        cursor = yield self.db.execute(query)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.2.1-py2.7-win32.egg\tornado\gen.py", line 870, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.2.1-py2.7-win32.egg\tornado\concurrent.py", line 215, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "D:\work\program-stat\momoko\connection.py", line 453, in when_available
        future_or_result = method(conn, *args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\work\program-stat\momoko\connection.py", line 743, in execute
        cursor.execute(operation, parameters)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extras.py", line 288, in execute
        return super(NamedTupleCursor, self).execute(query, vars)
    OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

Here is a code:

```
import os
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import momoko

from tornadotools.route import Route
from psycopg2.extras import NamedTupleCursor

import environments as env


tornado.options.define("port", default=9999, help="run on the given port", type=int)
tornado.options.define("pgsql_host", default=env.DB_HOST, help="database host")
tornado.options.define("pgsql_database", default=env.DB_DATABASE, help="database name")
tornado.options.define("pgsql_user", default=env.DB_LOGIN, help="database user")
tornado.options.define("pgsql_password", default=env.DB_PASSWORD, help="database password")


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = Route.routes()
        settings = dict(
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
            debug=True,
        )
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

        # Have one global connection to DB across all handlers
        self.db = momoko.Pool(
            dsn='dbname=%s user=%s password=%s '
                'host=%s port=5432' % (
                    tornado.options.options.pgsql_database,
                    tornado.options.options.pgsql_user,
                    tornado.options.options.pgsql_password,
                    tornado.options.options.pgsql_host),
            cursor_factory=NamedTupleCursor,
        )
        self.db.connect()


class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @property
    def db(self):
        return self.application.db

@Route(r"/")
class HomeHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("<ul>")
        self.write("<li><a href='/test'>Test page</a>")
        self.write("</ul>")
        self.finish()

@Route(r"/test")
class MogrifyHandler(BaseHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        cursor = yield self.db.execute("SELECT %s as t;", (1,))
        self.render("test.html", result=cursor.fetchall())


def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(tornado.options.options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How could I handle this exception and reconnect to db automatically without restarting app?

Answer (score 2):

## Tornado/Momoko/AutoReload

### Problem:

If the connection to the database Postgres distructed - momoko can not re-create the connection pool.
To solve this problem you need to restart the application. To automate this process, I wrote a small script that use the built-in tornado update mechanism.

### Solution:

Test every 1 second that database connection is alive.
Add this check before you start ioloop.

import reload
check_connect = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(lambda: reload.reload_if_db_pool_is_dead(application.db), 1000)
check_connect.start()

https://gist.github.com/MaxRV/d7180e63d6b5396d904d446653aa7e88

Answer (score 0):

you can add parameter:

```
raise_connect_errors=False,
```

When you create the connection pool:

```
self.db = momoko.Pool(
    dsn='dbname=%s user=%s password=%s '
        'host=%s port=5432' % (
            tornado.options.options.pgsql_database,
            tornado.options.options.pgsql_user,
            tornado.options.options.pgsql_password,
            tornado.options.options.pgsql_host),
    cursor_factory=NamedTupleCursor,
    raise_connect_errors=False,
)
```

But it is not always helpful.